# How can I display the message if username is valid in mvc3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am checking in database for usernames whether usernames typed are accepted or that username is already taken. I want to display message if the username is accepted entered by user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the tags you've used mean that you want to do this with jQuery, so here goes:

In your view, you'll have a textbox to allow users to enter a username:

```
<input id="username-txt" type="text" />
```

You'll also have a link or button that allows users to check if their username is already taken:

```
<a id="username-check" href="#">
```

Then you'll have a bit of javascript which is called when the link is clicked. The js will get the username and call your MVC action via ajax, and show an alert depending on the result:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#username-check").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name-to-check = $("username-txt").val();
    $.ajax({
          url: 'MyController/CheckUserName,
          type: 'POST',
          data: { username : name-to-check },
          success: function (data) {
             if (data.error != null) {
                alert(data.error_detail);
              } else {
                if(existingNames == 'true'){
                   alert('that username is taken');
                 }else{
                    alert('that username is available');
                 }
              }
          },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
             }
         });
    });
});
</script>
```

This javascript can be in the view, the _Layout file, or a separate .js file.  You'll need to include jQuery to make this work:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is your controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CheckUserName(string username)
{
   // here you'd make a database call to check if the username existed
   bool existingNames = MyService.UserNameExists(username);

return new JsonResult
 {
     Data = existingNames,
     JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
 };
}
```

This is obviously a simplified solution but it should get you started. Assuming this is actually what you want!